# django signals received by only one function

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a model that sends signal:

```
class WMTransaction(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status == 'completed':
            self.completed = datetime.datetime.now()
            try:
                old = WMTransaction.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
                if old.status == 'processing':
                    print 'sending signal'
                    payment_done.send(self)
            except:
                pass
        super(WMTransaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also I have receivers in 2 modules:

```
@receiver(payment_done, dispatch_uid="make_this_signal_unique", weak=False)
def subscribe(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'subscribing'
    # processing
```

And:

```
@receiver(payment_done, dispatch_uid="this_signal_is_also_unique", weak=False)
def buy(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'buying'
    # processing
```

The problem is that **subscribe** function is called, and **buy** - isn't... Both modules are in installed apps, other functions from these modules work correctly. What's the problem with signals?

Comment: Are both signal handlers in `models.py` or imported into `models.py`?

Comment: **subscribe** is in module_A.models and **buy** is in module_B.models

Comment: very unlikely, but try add some logging info into except block, if there isn't throwed some exception

Comment: Yeah, actually *never ever ever* use naked `except: pass`. As a first step, replace with `except WMTransaction.DoesNotExist:`, see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, `except: pass` is bad ) But the problem is not in `WMTransaction`, because the signal is really sent, string _subscribing_ is in logs, so that **subscribe** function is called... but there's no string _buying_ in logs

Comment: And yes, I replaced with `except Exception as e: print e`, it doesn't print anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has module_B been installed and the definition of `buy` actually gets executed? Check `payment_done.receivers` before the `payment_done.send` line.

Comment: Yes, it appears that this definition isn't executed: payment_done.receivers prints `[(('make_this_signal_unique', 139659700131376), <function subscribe at 0x7f051f2c3230>)]`. But why? Classes, defined in that file work normally.

Comment: @ookami.kb well, what's the state of payment_done after `buy` definition? Is there any disconnect afterwards?

Comment: BTW, what Python and env do you use?

Comment: python 2.6, django 1.3. well I simply moved 2nd function to other modeule and it worked... so the problem was definitely in that module...

Comment: @ookami.kb OK. Probably its because of weak=False, thread locking or importing ordering. If you figure out the reason later, I would like to know =)

Comment: I don't think this is because of weak - I added it later, before that it didn't work either. I suspect I have a mistake somewhere with import...